# Makefile relinks everytime

Tags: makefile

I can't figure out why my Makefile relinks every time. Could someone explain to me?

Here is my Makefile :

```
SRCS    = ${wildcard ./srcs/*.c}
OBJS    = ${SRCS:.c=.o}
INCL    = includes
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
NAME    = BSQ

.c.o :
            ${CC} -I ${INCL} ${CFLAGS} -c $< -o ${<:.c=.o}
all :       ${OBJS}
            ${CC} -o ${NAME} ${OBJS}
clean :
            rm -f ${OBJS}
fclean :    clean
            rm -f ${NAME}
re :        fclean all
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718392/how-to-avoid-my-makefile-to-relink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `all` target doesn't create a file named `all`, so `make` doesn't know that it has already been done.

You should make `all` depend on `${NAME}`, and then add a target for `${NAME}` that performs the linking.

```
all: ${NAME}

${NAME}: ${OBJS}
    ${CC} -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Even better, use `-o $@` since it is good Makefile hygiene to use $@ in any non-PHONY rule. Plus using $^ while we're at it.